# Matplotlib widget - many radiobuttons issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to set height of the matplotlib widget, change alignment or change font but i don't know how.

**Screenshots:**

5 radio buttons:
[image]

15 radio buttons:
[image]

And here is the critical code part:

```
def evolvecallback_(self, notification):
    global i
    stats={}
    results=[]
    fitnesses=[]

    for code,fit in evolve(i):
        results.append(code)
        stats[str(fit)]=code
        fitnesses.append(str(fit))
    i+=1
    fig = plt.figure() 
    done=""

    if found():
        done=" - Solution found!"
        print "Done!"

    fig.canvas.set_window_title("Generation "+str(i)+". - Best migrating individuals"+done) 


    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(stats[str(fitnesses[0])])
    l, = ax.plot(x, s0, lw=2, color='blue')
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)

    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)

    radio = RadioButtons(rax, tuple(fitnesses))
    def change(label):
        hzdict = {}
        x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.01)
        j=0
        for i in tuple(results):
            hzdict[fitnesses[j]]=eval(i)
            j+=1
        ax.set_title(stats[str(label)])
        ydata = hzdict[str(label)]
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()
    radio.on_clicked(change)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

This line sets where and how big the axes the radio buttons are drawn onto is:

```
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)
```

Change it to something like

```
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.3, 0.15, 0.5], axisbg=axcolor)
```

[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes)

To be clear, `rax` is just an `axes` object to which you are adding the radio button widgets to.

Comment: Hi,  I've got the same issue (and so does this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997920/matplotlib-radio-button-scaling).  I think it might be a bug.  I've tried adjusting the axis, `rax`, but to no avail.  It just ends up weirdly distorting the radiobutton.  Do you know of a solution/workaround?

Comment: @Jean-Luc Thanks for kicking me on this.  This looks like it is an issue with how the buttons are made (drawn as circles) and the aspect ratio of the axes.

Comment: Yep!  That's exactly what I was thinking.  Do you know if this is a bug, or if there is some other way to do it that perhaps scales everything properly?  Should I file a bug report or...?

Comment: Yes, please file a bug report, the buttons are not parameterized super well.

Comment: @tacaswell Do you know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095111/displaying-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-matplotlib